# The need for the multithreading in javafx

Tags: multithreading, javafx, cmusphinx

I'm new to javafx and I have a question. My project is a voice browser with some simple command but I have an issue in switch(). The command at lines one and three of first case statement work, but line 2 does not. But if I remove the while loop, it works well! I have no idea how to solve this, help me please!

Here is my code

```
btSpeak.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    new Task<Void>(){
         public Void call(){
        int click=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Bạn đã sẵn sàng trải nghiệm với VoiceCommand chưa", "Speak", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if(click==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Start", "Speak", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            // code for voice recognize
            try {
                URL url;
                url = HelloWorld.class.getResource("helloworld.config.xml");
                System.out.println("Loading..."+url.toString());
                ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager(url);
                final Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
                Microphone microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");


                /* allocate the resource necessary for the recognizer */
                recognizer.allocate();

                /* the microphone will keep recording until the program exits */



                if (microphone.startRecording())
                {
                    System.out.println("Say: (Leen | Xuoongs| Trais | Phair | DDi |Veef| Dongs-Tab|Mowr-Tab| Noi - Dung| Trang-Chur|Trang-Truoc)") ;


                    System.out.println("Start speaking. Press Ctrl-C to quit.\n");

                    /*
                     * This method will return when the end of speech
                     * is reached. Note that the endpointer will determine
                     * the end of speech.
                     */
                    //   Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                    //    public void run(){
                    int i = 0;
                    while(i< 5) {
                        //Thread.this.notifyAll();
                        Result result = recognizer.recognize();
                        if (result != null)
                        {
                            int t = 0;
                            System.out.println("Enter your choise"+ "\n");
                            resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();
                            System.out.println("You said: " + resultText + "\n");
                            if(resultText.equals("xuoongs")) {
                                t = 1;
                            } else if(resultText.equals("leen")) {
                                t = 2;
                            }

                            switch(t) {
                            case 1: {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "xuống");//line 1
                                webEngine.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,100)");line 2
                                break;// line 3
                            }
                            case 2: {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "lên");
                                webEngine.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-100)");
                                break;
                            }
                            }// end switch
                        }// end if
                    }//end while()
                }// end if
            } catch (PropertyException e) {
                System.err.println("Problem configuring HelloWorld: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     }
     }.run());
    }// end button
});
```

Comment: Yes, you need to run resource-consuming recognition process in a separate thread. Currently you are not doing that.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Can you show me how could i do that? Because im try do that but it doesn't work at all!!! Thanks you!!

Comment: Sure, show the code you tried, describe what doesn't work exactly and we'll be able to help you.

Comment: I set it in a Thread  Task and run it in Gui code.But it still jump over line 2 in case 1.Line 2 never be executed, but when i remove the while loop, it work well, i mean, line 1,2,3 are executed sequently!!!

Comment: No, this is wrong, you need to run recognize in thread only, the rest must be in UI thread. Otherwise you block UI update with the next recognize call.